# Need js/jquery code to refresh (not reload) contents within that dive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery/js can anyone rearrange below code in a manner it sends request to server in every 5 seconds to refresh contents within that div.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(

            function() {

                setInterval(function() {

                    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

                    $('#show').text(

                            'I am getting refreshed every 3 seconds..! Random Number ==> '

                                    + randomnumber);

                }, 3000);

            });

</script>


<div id="show" align="center"></div>
```

Please note: code is within same page and there is no any other page to get date from that

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($){
    $(function(){

    setInterval(function() {

        $.ajax({
          url: "test.php"
        }).done(function( data ) {
          $( '#target_div' ).text( "Data from server:" + data.toString() );
        });

    }, 3000);

    });
})(jQuery);
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Dear Sir, i don't have any external file to get data from. there is a div in which i have placed time ago function like facebook (2 seconds ago). Now i want to develop a code that refresh contents within that div. so that time changes after each 5 seconds. This time ago code is stored in database.